# Extract limited set of date patterns

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have the following text string:

```
s = """Today is Mar 4, 2014 and tomorrow will be 2014-03-05
       and yesterday was 03/03/2014 and now it is currently 2014-03-04 02:02:03"""
```

What would be the best way to extract these four date patterns from the text? I was thinking a regex solution for each pattern, such as:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}', s)
['2014-03-05', '2014-03-04']
```

But then it gets a bit tricky because I need to remove the previously-used items and go in order (for example, to do datetime before date).

What would be a good solution for the above?

Here is what I have so far:

```
>>> ACCEPTABLE_REGEX_DATETIME_PATTERNS = [
...     r'\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}',
...     r'\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}',
...     r'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}',
...     r'[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\.?\s\d{1,2}\,?\s\d{2,4}'
... ]
>>> for pattern in ACCEPTABLE_REGEX_DATETIME_PATTERNS:
...     re.findall(pattern, s)
... 
['2014-03-04 02:02:03']
['2014-03-05', '2014-03-04'] # this is wrong
['03/03/2014']
['Mar 4, 2014']
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression might be also close to what you wish to write:

```
import re

regex = r"[A-Z](?:[a-z]{2,}\.?)?\s+\d{1,2}\s*,?\s+\d{2,4}|\d{4}(?:-\d{1,2}){2}(?:\s+\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2}){2})?|\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}"

test_str = """
Today is Mar 4, 2014 and tomorrow will be 2014-03-05 and yesterday was 03/03/2014 and now it is currently 2014-03-04 02:02:03
Today is M 4, 2015 and tomorrow will be 2015-03-05 and yesterday was 03/03/2015 and now it is currently 2015-03-04 02:02:03
Today is Mar. 4, 2016 and tomorrow will be 2016-03-05 and yesterday was 03/03/2016 and now it is currently 2016-03-04 02:02:03
Today is March 4, 2017 and tomorrow will be 2017-03-05 and yesterday was 03/03/2017 and now it is currently 2017-03-04 02:02:03
"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['Mar 4, 2014', '2014-03-05', '03/03/2014', '2014-03-04 02:02:03', 'M 4, 2015', '2015-03-05', '03/03/2015', '2015-03-04 02:02:03', 'Mar. 4, 2016', '2016-03-05', '03/03/2016', '2016-03-04 02:02:03', 'March 4, 2017', '2017-03-05', '03/03/2017', '2017-03-04 02:02:03']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/w1Vw6O/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/w1Vw6O/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For basic validation, you can try combining the regex, like this:

```
ACCEPTABLE_REGEX_DATETIME_PATTERNS = [
    r'\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}',
    r'\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}',
    r'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}',
    r'[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\.?\s\d{1,2}\,?\s\d{2,4}'
]
dt_regex = re.compile( '|'.join( ACCEPTABLE_REGEX_DATETIME_PATTERNS) )
re.findall(dt_regex, s)
```

> ['Mar 4, 2014', '2014-03-05', '03/03/2014', '2014-03-04 02:02:03']